# Does using documentFragment cause a reflow/repaint?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just out of interest does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: as far as I know: no. But if you add it as child to the DOM than it might happen.

Comment: Yeah that's what I assumed, the second we append to the visual DOM we'll get a reflow. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MozDev (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment)

> Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document fragments often results in better performance.

Answer (score 2):

The whole  intend of documentFragments is to *not* cause any re-paints/flows. By using a documentFragment to reflect your changes and after that appending it to the DOM, you save a lot of time for re-flows/paints.

Comment: Thanks. Working on reducing reflow as much as possible on our mobile web app and this seems perfect for building DOM